# Using as.hexmode with R

Tags: r, hex

I have some R code:

```
 writePoint <- page * 2^12 + offset
 localCount<-0
 instructions <- 0
 while(localCount < lengthI$length) {
    cat("<instruction address=\"")
    cat(as.hexmode(writePoint))
```

However `writePoint` is always written as a decimal number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK - guessing - I am passing a function as a parameter and R doesn't like that - how do I fix that?

Comment: Well, it's defined there - I suppose I can make it what I like - I have assumed it's a double

Comment: Please make your example reproducible and describe your expected output.

Comment: Nothing to do with passing functions as a parameter. That's perfectly legal in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's kind of interesting. Here's a bit more compact demonstration and a start toward an explanation:

```
> cat(as.hexmode(10))
10
> cat(as.hexmode(20))
20
> as.hexmode(20)
[1] "14"

> str(as.hexmode(20))
Class 'hexmode'  int 20
```

So a hexmode number has a print method (seen by typing `methods(print)` at the console) and it coerces it to a character when it is printed but it doesn't really change its internal representation as a number, so `cat` give you back a decimal number. Notice that the help page for `cat` says (but I will admit this behavior was not really implied by this text and I would have thought that it meant that cat would give 14 or 0x14):

```
> 0x14
[1] 20
```

> cat converts numeric/complex elements in the same way as print (and not in the same way as as.character which is used by the S equivalent), so options "digits" and "scipen" are relevant.

Might want to use the as.character coercion to get what you want:

```
>  as.character(as.hexmode(20))
[1] "14"
```

Comment: Really the same thing, no? The `as.character.hexmode` function is really a call to `format.hexmode`

Comment: This works - up to a point see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873318/using-as-hexmode-in-r-to-handle-a-double

Comment: I see you are both the questioner and the answerer there. It was unclear to me what error condition you were creating. It appeared that you were offering code but no input to test with.