# Using as.hexmode in R to handle a double

Tags: r, hex

I have an intermittent problem with `as.hexmode` in R.

Following good advice in response to a previous question I now have code that looks like this:

```
WriteOutRW<- function(page, offset, lengthI) {
#  writePoint <- bitwShiftL(page, 12)
  writePoint <- page * 2^12 + offset
  localCount<-0
  instructions <- 0
  while(localCount < lengthI$length) {
    if (runif(1, 0, 1) > 0.9) {
      cat("<modify")
    } else {
      cat("<load")
    }
  cat(" address=\"")
  cat(as.character(as.hexmode(writePoint)))
  .
  .
  .
```

This produces output like this...

```
<instruction address="4d0bff" size="3" />
<instruction address="4d0c02" size="2" />
<load address="4e36e0" size="c" />
<load address="4e36ec" size="1" />
<load address="4e36ed" size="1" />
<load address="4e36ee" size="2" />
<instruction address="4d0328" size="2" />
<instruction address="4d032a" size="2" />
<modify address="4df2dd" size="1" />
<load address="4df2de" size="1" />
<modify address="4df2df" size="2" />
<instruction address="4d0204" size="2" />
<instruction address="4d0206" size="1" />
<instruction address="4d0207" size="1" />
<load address="Error in if (is.double(x) && (x == as.integer(x))) x <- as.integer(x) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: WriteOutRW -> cat -> as.hexmode
In addition: Warning message:
In as.hexmode(writePoint) : NAs introduced by coercion
Execution halted
```

The `instruction` elements are produced by a very similar function - though the `address` there can never be a double - and it never fails. My assumption is that the `WriteOutRW` function is failing when `writePoint` is a double. But `as.hexmode` should handle doubles, shouldn't it?

**update** Just to be clear I am trying to process integers here (of type Integer and Double) and the numbers print out as base 10 decimals without a problem, but I really want hex output.

Comment: Do you mean like `as.hexmode(3.14)`? Because that gives an error.

Comment: `as.hexmode` and/or `?as.hexmode` have the answers to this.. "integers (of type 'integer' or 'double') and character vectors whose elements contain only 0-9, a-f, A-F (or are NA)"

Comment: No, definitely not of type 3.14 - and rawr I don't understand your comment - I am trying to process a double of exactly that type (I did read the helpfile, that's why I am puzzled)

Comment: print all of the `as.integer(writePoint)`s then

Comment: Can you give an example value here that produces the problem? I don't understand where the error is. It appears the largest double you can convert is `as.hexmode(as.double(2147483647))`. Is your value larger than that?

Comment: yes, it probably is. eg it fails with 68702675777 - I am having the same sort of problem with sprintf too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote my own hex printing code in the end:

```
HexChar<-function(number) {
  x<-as.integer(number%%16)
  str<-as.character(as.hexmode(x))
  return (str)
}

HexString<-function(numberX) {
  number <- as.double(numberX)
  stringy<-""
  for (i in 1:16) {
    stringy<-paste(HexChar(number), stringy, sep="")
    number <- number/16
  }
  return (stringy)
}
```